# How can I change the time zone in Fabric?

Tags: timezone, twitter-fabric, fabric.io, google-fabric

Can I change the time zone in Fabric? Fabric got the UTC, but we located in other time zone. So when we checked the data in Fabric, we would be confused by the time.
[UTC time zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4s7c.png)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ah, currently I think there is not a way to change the timezone cause all the way to change timezone are based on the UTC.

Comment: I know that. Is there any option changes timezone from UTC to UTC +2  in Fabric?

Comment: No bro, it isn't, they are working on it. I'm sorry :(

Comment: Thank u all the same, bro.

Comment: Fabric says they've been working on it for years and we still don't have time zone support. How can this be so difficult?

Comment: this should not be difficult but may be with low priority

Comment: It's too easy to implement that nobody has the spare time for it.