# Change time when Fabric DAU gets reset

Tags: twitter-fabric, google-fabric

Our app is mostly focused on US users. And Fabric analytics data (DAU/crashes) gets reset every day at 3PM. How can we set a time for analytics reset more relevant for US timezone (ie midnight pacific time)?

Comment: It looks like there is still no way of doing this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43338481/how-can-i-change-the-time-zone-in-fabric?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the time zone in Fabric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43338481/how-can-i-change-the-time-zone-in-fabric)